# Sql query for union of 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with a query. I have two tables and both have one column in common, but the data in both may differ:

**tab 1**

```
+---------+------------+
|   Sub   | student_id |
+---------+------------+
| Math    | 0033       |
| Science | 0034       |
| Geom    | 0035       |
| Math    | 0034       |
+---------+------------+
```

**tab 2**

```
+---------+----------+
|   Sub   | class_id |
+---------+----------+
| Science | 001      |
| Geom    | 002      |
| Geom    | 001      |
| Civics  | 004      |
+---------+----------+
```

Now I need the results in the following way:

```
+---------+----------------+--------------+
|   Sub   | Student(count) | Class(count) |
+---------+----------------+--------------+
| Math    | 2              | 0            |
| Science | 1              | 1            |
| Geom    | 1              | 2            |
| Civics  | 0              | 1            |
+---------+----------------+--------------+
```

I think I have to use union and I can get results in two different queries, but I am not able to show the final table as above.

This is what I have:

```
select sub,count(*)as student_id from tab1
group by sub
union
select sub,count(*)as class_id from tab2
group by sub
```

But I get 2 cols out of it instead of 3.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
SELECT AllSubs.Sub as Sub,
       COUNT(DISTINCT tab1.Student_Id) as "Student(Count)",
       COUNT(DISTINCT tab2.Class_Id) as "Class(Count)"
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Sub FROM tab1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Sub FROM tab2)AllSubs
LEFT JOIN tab1 ON tab1.Sub = AllSubs.Sub
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab2.Sub = AllSubs.Sub
GROUP BY AllSubs.Sub
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/222f1b/1)

the query select all distinct subjects from tab1 and tab2 then left joins with tab1 and tab2, then counts distinct studdent_id and counts distinct class_id grouping by subject.

### UPDATED

```
SELECT AllSubs.Sub as Sub,
       COUNT(DISTINCT tab1.Student_Id) as "Student(Count)",
       COUNT(DISTINCT tab2.Class_Id) as "Class(Count)",
       COUNT(DISTINCT tab1.Student_Id) - COUNT(DISTINCT tab2.Class_Id) as difference
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Sub FROM tab1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Sub FROM tab2)AllSubs
LEFT JOIN tab1 ON tab1.Sub = AllSubs.Sub
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab2.Sub = AllSubs.Sub
GROUP BY AllSubs.Sub
ORDER BY difference DESC
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/222f1b/2)

If you just want the first row, just add `LIMIT 1` to the end of query.

Comment: great works perfect thanks a lot. Now if I have to extend it to find the ratio of student(count) vs class(count) do I have to find the difference somewhere

Comment: not sure what you mean by ratio of student(count) vs class(count). you can just select those values and do math on them if you like. What values are you expecting to see (in another column?)

Comment: Output the name of the subject that has the highest ratio of students enrolled for that subject versus class having that skill.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean, can you show me your expected result set?

Comment: Output the name of the subject that has the highest ratio of students enrolled for that subject versus class having that subject.... So in above case we should get the results as just Subject - Math.    As we have 2 students taking it but no class teaching it. In short I need the subject with highest difference between its student count and class count.